# Windows 10 Shortcuts look weird?

Tags: windows-10

Okay so... I just woke up and went to my computer... This is what appeared on my programs/shortcuts.
Running a virus scan, I am just wondering if any of you have been experiencing this aswell... Sometimes they also change from that X to a green correct symbol.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have setup a cloud synchronization program to sync your desktop shortcuts.  Use something like Autoruns to disable all startup processes except what is required for your system to function, see if the problem remains, its also possible your infected with Malware.

Comment: Could it be Filezilla?

Comment: You tell me.  Stop running Filezilla and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I stopped explorer.exe and started it again... Not they are gone. Found this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3h5332/windows_10_shortcuts_now_have_a_green_check_mark/

Comment: Guessing it is windows 10?

Comment: This has nothing to do with you running Windows 10.  This is not a default feature of Windows 10.  You have software running on your machine that is doing this.  What does "not they are gone" mean exactly?

Comment: oh sorry. Now they are gone. The virus scan showed nothing. Want me to show you my installed programs?

Comment: Found this. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/onedrive-upgrade-desktop-app Pretty sure it is one drive

Comment: OneDrive even on Windows 10 by default does not attempt to synchronize your shortcuts on your desktop.  The linked article only applies to Windows 8 and Windows 8.1.  If it was OneDrive doing this, restarting Explorer.exe, wouldn't have gotten rid of those checkmarks and the x's

Comment: I don't have anything else that synchronizes. Could it be my intel rapid storage program or what it is called?

Comment: No, There isn't Intel software that would do this.

Comment: Any ideas why? I have no programs that would do that.

Comment: I already told you how to determine the reason in my very first comment.

Comment: Okay, last question. Could it be my Windows Defender? It is checked to Real-time protection, Skybased Protection and to send information to microsoft.

Comment: Windows Defender does not have a feature that would explain the problem you face.

Comment: Nevermind... Not my last question. This should be though. Looked through my registry files. Found some keys called OneDrive1 Onedrive2 OneDrive3 OneDrive4 OneDrive5 and EnhancedStorageShell. Could it be the EnhancedStorageShell doing it?

Comment: No; I have that key and my desktop does not look like that.

Comment: Well, not happening anymore. Besides that, I don't have any backup programs. Guessing it's a bug, because it kept changing from the check, to the X, and then to a freaking home group logo.